# Adding number in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add numbers with 3 EditTexts and I want to display it on text view with a calculate button but there's something wrong with Kotlin code as I'm newbie

Here's my code:

```
class Add : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adsense)
        var input_num1 = num1
        var input_num2 = numm2
        var input_num3 = num3

        result.setOnCLickListener {
            var result = input_num1.toStrubg()?.toLong() +  input_num2.toStrubg()?.toLong() + input_num3.toLong()?.toString()
        }
    }
}

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/num1"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/num2"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/num3"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Result" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Calculate"
    android:onClick="Calculate"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Comment: What is toStrubg()? Also why are you adding two longs and a string. I think your problem might be that you haven't proofread your code.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are a newbie but that doesn't mean you will have to ignore the compiler or IDE errors. Clearly `toStrubg()` is not a keyword and your IDE will make you aware of that. Don't know what the rest of your code looks like so will help you with the `result.setOnClickListener`.

Try this

```
result.setOnClickListener {
        var result = input_num1.toString()?.toLong() +  input_num2.toString()?.toLong() + input_num3.toString()?.toLong()
    }
```

Also I'll advise that you should try and learn Kotlin first before embarking on your Android development journey. Here are some links to help you.
[Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/)
[try](https://try.kotlinlang.org)

Comment: Its showing num1, num2, num3, result. Their references not found error